# .htaccess: how to restrict access to specific images from my mobile site

Tags: .htaccess

For my mobile site I want to restrict access for some of my images like "lady bug.gif" "bluemoon.gif" etc. So these images won't be shown in http://m.mysite.org for faster and less clutter mobile experience. How can I do this?

Not working example:

```
 rewriteEngine On
<files bluemoon.gif>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be better off internally rewriting to a small 1px image, rather than simply blocking access. If you block access (404, 403, etc) then you would end up with errors in your front end.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =m.mysite.org
RewriteRule (lady\sbug|bluemoon)\.gif$ /images/mobile-placeholder.gif [L]
```

Note that if you have spaces in your filenames then you will need to replace these with `\s` in the `RewriteRule` pattern (a regular expression) - as above.

Comment: There's space in most of my images. I've uploaded placeholder gif but your code doesn't work for both images.

You can see bluemoon.gif (a blue moon image) if you scroll down to bottom of the page . http://m.aymavisi.org/site/21%20Edebiyat.htm?imz_st

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =m.aymavisi.org

RewriteRule (ladybug|bluemoon).gif$ /images/mobile-placeholder.gif

Comment: I've changed the answer with respect to spaces (also added the `Options` directive). You have unusual filenames, however, this should still work. Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file? Is it enabled? Is mod_rewrite enabled? This `.htaccess` file is presumably in the root of your site?

Comment: Nothing else in my .htaccess file, it's in root folder. Previously I used my .htaccess file for redirecting and it was working fine so I can say it's enabled. But with new code still I can see blue moon on bottom of my mobile page. BTW my image files in a folder called img.

Comment: The above should work, providing the _host_ and image paths are set correctly. Try removing (or commenting out) the `RewriteCond` directive. If that still doesn't work then just try entering _anything_ in the .htaccess file - do you get an error?

Comment: Removing RewriteCond doesn't help. Entering something like 'abcde' gives Internal Server Error. Blocking all gif files also okay for me, could you provide such a code to se if it'll work or not?

Comment: Do you have any other .htaccess files (in subdirectories)? Any rules in your server config? How is your site generating the custom (soft) 404 page? You mentioned that your "image files in a folder called img", however, the "...bluemoon.gif" file appears to be in a folder called `/i`?

Comment: I have no subdirectory with .htaccess files. I create 404 pages adding error404.html file to root of my site. Images actually in root>img directory but I created my mobile site automatically using 1&1 Mobile Website Creator. So I can't gain access mobile site via FTP nor via 1&1 control panel. I guess this means I shouldn't have upload .htaccess to my desktop site www.aymavisi.org?

Comment: "I create 404 pages adding error404.html" - Although there must be some setting/config that calls this page in the event of a 404? This is also another problem: your mobile site doesn't return a 404 status code, but your desktop site does. "Images actually in root>img" - Well, the image URLs on your mobile site are of the form `/i/http%3A%2F%2Faymavisi.org%2F%2Fimg%2Fbluemoon.gif` which suggests they are in an `i` directory. I mentioned earlier that these URLs are "unusual" - an encoded slash (`%2F`) will break a default Apache setup.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "1&1 Mobile Website Creator", but if you can't access the site then that could certainly be a problem! Where exactly is `m.example.org` (your mobile site) located? Is it on the same file system as your desktop site (although if it was I would assume it would be accessible)? The above .htaccess file needs to be uploaded to the document root of your _mobile site_.

Comment: Using control panel of 1&1 I see Complete web server path for m.aymavisi.org: /kunden/homepages/7/d205910720/htdocs & Target directory: / there's no such directory in my desktop site. I guess 1&1 use some sort cloud based server to convert requested desktop pages to mobile pages. Because desktop page changes instantly shown on mobile site. About 404 pages only method is here: https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/webspace-and-access-c85098/webfiles-c42846/create-custom-error-pages-a631149.html

Comment: You could try changing the above _internal rewrite_ into an _external redirect_ ie. change the flags on the `RewriteRule` from `[L]` to `[R,L]` - if the mobile site is dynamically generated by making HTTP requests to the desktop version then this might work? You will need to remove the `RewriteCond` directive also, which will mean (temporarily) that this will also affect your desktop site.

Comment: I uploaded the code but nothing changed: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (bluemoon)\.gif$ /images/mobile-placeholder.gif [R,L]

Comment: Do you see a change on your desktop site? Do you have the `Options` directive? You will obviously need to change `/images/mobile-placeholder.gif` to something appropriate for your site, although if that is invalid it will simply result in a 404, so not the cause of this problem.

Comment: Yes, for desktop site, I see bluemoon.gif replaced with the image I specified with this code: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (lady\sbug|bluemoon)\.gif$ /img/ara.gif [R,L]

Comment: You mention that "desktop page changes instantly show on mobile site" - how "instant". However, on the other page you link to regarding the error document states that, "It takes about 15-30 minutes for these custom error pages to work." - it might be unrelated, but just wondered.

Comment: It takes about 15-30 minutes" should be only for the new or updated custom error pages.